# I downloaded Ubuntu mate for Raspberry pi and installed it but it won't boot

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu

Installed image on 32GB micro SD:
sudo ddrescue -D --force ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img /dev/sdd
Displays message indicating  a crash but won't boot

Comment: What Pi are you using? Pi 1, Pi 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using PI 2. I've downloaded Raspberian and that works.

Comment: I've downloaded Ubuntu mate several times, always with the same   results.It outputs 16 lines beginning with:

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu mate will only run on a Pi 2 onwards so if you are trying this on a Pi 1 it won't work.

`shasum -a 256 ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img`

Check the hash of your download to make sure it matches the ones given on the [downsite site](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) (may may have to look around for the right hash if you are using an older version). It might be a corrupt .img.

You could use `sudo dd if=ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.im of=/dev/sdd bs=4M` to write the image. The Ubuntu Mate folk seem to suggest the `ddrescue` method as preferred but I've tended towards regular dd, Can't see it making that much difference though. **Make absolutely certain `/dev/sdd` is your SD-Card mind :)**

SD Card definitely healthy though right?